# Plug sdramps module and Anet A8 LCD together into RAMPS smart adapter

Tags: ramps-1.4, anet-a8, wiring, microsd, sd

I want to upgrade my Anet A8's motherboard (the stock one is broken anyway, see: [Anet A8 reading 739°C from the extruder thermistor!](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/anet-a8-reading-739c-from-the-extruder-thermistor)) to the RAMPS 1.4, without having to get a new LCD/microSD module. I am thinking of getting both a smart adapter and sdramps, then maybe plug the sdramps and the stock Anet A8 LCD into the smart adapter, but I am not sure whether the sdramps module has a different pinout than the RAMPS smart controller, which is what the smart adapter is made for.

Can someone confirm whether they have the same pinouts or not, or give me some alternatives to my idea?

Comment: I've seen the other way around where someone connects a rep rap LCD to the board: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2103748

Comment: The link above gives you information on the pin layout which you can compare to the layout on the RAMPS. You know there is a 1.6 version which has improvements on MOSFET cooling and more copper in the traces?

Comment: @0scar it is easy the other way around, but I want to keep the stock LCD in order to save some money.

Comment: @0scar 1.6 has SMD fuses, which are much harder to replace than removable fuses, or even through-hole soldered ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Anet A8 uses a simple LCD with 5 buttons, the problem is that the buttons do not use digital pin signals, instead analog pins are used. Based on the pressed button, with corresponding resistance the firmware knows which button is pressed. The RAMPS smart adapter uses digital pins, so **the Anet LCD is not compatible with the smart adapter**, you may wan't to opt for a cheap Chinese 12864 LCD smart controller, they are about $8, they are compatible.

---

The topic [Connecting (Anet A8) 2004 display to MKS GEN L](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6030/connecting-anet-a8-2004-display-to-mks-gen-l) shows you to hook up the Anet A8 LCD to a RAMPS board. You **do not use the smart adapter**, instead **you use AUX2**. You only have to change 2 wires (interchange them on AUX2) and you will be able to use the display. The reason you cannot use the smart adapter is that the 5 button display requires analog pins, which are not available on the smart adapter, but are available on the AUX2 header.