# Anet A8 display on MKS Gen L board

Tags: marlin, anet-a8

So I have read this question, [Connecting (Anet A8) 2004 display to MKS GEN L](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6030/connecting-anet-a8-2004-display-to-mks-gen-l/6044#6044).

That looked so easy, so I rewired the connectors and switched the VCC and GND pins. In the Marlin firmware I disabled the `MKS GEN L` display and enabled the `ZONESTAR_LCD` and `ULTRA_LCD`.

Yet when I run the printer, I only get the fully white rectangles. Is there anything else I have to do?

I have a compilation warnings now, because the `ZONESTAR_LCD` redefines some of the pins that `ULTRA_LCD` sets, but I guess that is ok. Could it be caused by still including the `U8glib` library? Do I have to also remove some constant regarding this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3D printing.SE! SE websites are driven by questions and answers, your question is more a forum style comment to another question where you ask for help to start a discussion. This is not where the comment section should be used for. Please read the help section, accessible through the button with the question mark at the top right menu.

Comment: Hi Zdeněk and welcome to 3D printing :-)  I'm sorry that you can't leave comments yet.  Please don't let that put you off though and feel free to ask an original question, or post an answer to someone else's question. Hang around the site, try to earn some reputation and at a reputation of 50 you will be able to leave comments. Good luck in the future. Oh, and don't forget to take the [tour](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys I got it! It really was just what is the [answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6044/5740) in the other question ([Connecting (Anet A8) 2004 display to MKS GEN L](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6030/connecting-anet-a8-2004-display-to-mks-gen-l))!

**My problem was:** I used jumper cables and some duct tape to hold them together ... and **the only issue was, that I didn't insert it enough**. I got mad today and just pushed them really hard more into the AUX2 connector and it suddenly works!

Comment: Yeah, it's always a good idea to push the connector home firmly and fully. :-) I'm glad that you solved your problem.