# White blocks on LCD screen after Anet A8 power up

Tags: marlin, anet-a8

I just completed assembly of the Anet A8 and powered it up.

Powering up shows white blocks on LED and a series of clicking noise for about three seconds with flashing red LED. During power-up, the following happens:

- The side heat sink fans start (Blower fan remains off)
- LED comes up with all white blocks and buttons do nothing
- No motor moves in any way
- Motherboard show not light except a three-flash-red-LEDnear the corner (fan connector)
- Printer remains in the state
- Reset button only repeats the clicking sound + red flashing LED

Video: https://photos.app.goo.gl/mxNNeK5o13a9C6TC8

The display of the Anet A8 now shows white blocks.

Any hints as to what could be wrong?

**Update 1:**
The clicking sound is actually the blower powering up and then going off immediately after.

**Update 2:**
I just did a blind flash to Marlin 1.18 and the firmware deployed successfully. Now, the boot sequence is almost 4 secs longer (previously, it was 3) and the clicking sound of the blower fan slowly spinning is replaced by a high spin-up of the blower. but after that, we are back to a dead printer with all whites.

Comment: Hi Hassan and welcome to SE.3D Printing!

Comment: I bet that blinking red LED is an error code.  Hope someone has the spec sheet for your motherboard.    In the meantime, try the usual re-check that everything is connected to the correct port and properly seated.

Comment: The white blocks sounds like [Connecting (Anet A8) 2004 display to MKS GEN L](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6030/connecting-anet-a8-2004-display-to-mks-gen-l). Are the connectors pushed home correctly? See also [Anet A8 display on MKS Gen L board](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6418/anet-a8-display-on-mks-gen-l-board)

Comment: I can't play the video, "This video format is unsupported" apparently... Using Opera

Comment: @Greenonline It works fine in Chrome. As D1 never blinks he has a DOA board, this has happened so many times that GearBest put instructions on their site. I think I'm just lucky with my Anet A8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known and [documented problem](https://www.gearbest.com/blog/how-to/solve-anet-a8-3d-printer-black-screen-white-square-problems-2140) of this printer. I'm afraid your printer board is dead.

If you have white squares on the display like this picture:
[image]

> You need to check Anet A8's mainboard - click reset button and check
>   the D1 indicator:
>   [image]
>
> - If D1 lights on for a second then went out and the screen is full of white square, try to reconnect screen wire for several times. When
>     it's well connected, click the reset button. If still not working, you
>     need to replace a screen.
> - If the D1 indicator is always off and the screen is full of white square, you need to replace a mainboard.

From the video you posted it can be seen that the D1 LED does not light up, it is off the whole time. Hence the main board is dead.

Comment: D1 light never blinks.