# Prusa i3, MK3: Firmware updated to 3.8.0. Display shows white blocks

Tags: prusa-i3, firmware, slic3r, arduino-mega-2650

About the printer:

- Prusa I3 MK3 [Sintron]
- Arduino Mega 2560 (just replaced)
- Replaced LCD / Smart controller
- FIRMWARE 3.8.0

Steps I have already tried:

- Replaced faulty Arduino
- **Failed** to flash firmware with PrusaSlicer

> avrdude-slic3r: Could not open port: /dev/cu.usbmodem1421

- Connected using Pronterface
- Replaced LCD Display / Smart Controller

I replaced the Arduino on my I3 MK3 and have tried to flash firmware V 3.8.0. The AVRDUDE logs in Prusaslicer say the flash succeed. I haven't gotten any response from the printer. I also replaced the LCD display / Smart Interface to see if it was faulty.

The screen displays the same block-bar pattern. The heat bed starts to hear up, as well as the extruder tip, the extruder fan also runs. There is no response from the dial on the LCD display / interface. When I try to engage any of the stepper motors using Pronterface, nothing happens.

I have also already read this [this post](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6485/white-blocks-on-lcd-screen-after-anet-a8-power-up). I am hoping that the print shield isn't fried.

This is the log output after attempting to flash firmware using Prusaslicer:

```
avrdude-slic3r -v -p atmega2560 -c wiring -P /dev/cu.usbmodem1421 -b 115200 -D -U flash:w:0:/Users/james.johnson/Downloads/prusa3d_fw_3_8_0_MK3 (1)/prusa3d_fw_MK3_3_8_0_2684.hex:i

avrdude-slic3r: Version 6.3-20160220-prusa3d, compiled on Sep 16 2019 at 02:08:32
                Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
                Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch


                Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbmodem1421
                Using Programmer              : wiring
                Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
                AVR Part                      : ATmega2560
                Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
                PAGEL                         : PD7
                BS2                           : PA0
                RESET disposition             : dedicated
                RETRY pulse                   : SCK
                serial program mode           : yes
                parallel program mode         : yes
                Timeout                       : 200
                StabDelay                     : 100
                CmdexeDelay                   : 25
                SyncLoops                     : 32
                ByteDelay                     : 0
                PollIndex                     : 3
                PollValue                     : 0x53
                Memory Detail                 :

                                         Block Poll               Page                       Polled
                  Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
                  ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
                  eeprom        65    10     8    0 no       4096    8      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
                  flash         65    10   256    0 yes    262144  256   1024  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                  lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
                  hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
                  efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
                  lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
                  calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
                  signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

                Programmer Type : Wiring
                Description     : Wiring
                Programmer Model: AVRISP
                Hardware Version: 15
                Firmware Version Master : 2.10
                Vtarget         : 0.0 V
                SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude-slic3r: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude-slic3r: Device signature = 0x1e9801 (probably m2560)
avrdude-slic3r: reading input file "/Users/james.johnson/Downloads/prusa3d_fw_3_8_0_MK3 (1)/prusa3d_fw_MK3_3_8_0_2684.hex"
avrdude-slic3r: writing flash (244050 bytes):
avrdude-slic3r: stk500v2_command(): command failed

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 42.31s

avrdude-slic3r: 244050 bytes of flash written
avrdude-slic3r: verifying flash memory against /Users/james.johnson/Downloads/prusa3d_fw_3_8_0_MK3 (1)/prusa3d_fw_MK3_3_8_0_2684.hex:
avrdude-slic3r: load data flash data from input file /Users/james.johnson/Downloads/prusa3d_fw_3_8_0_MK3 (1)/prusa3d_fw_MK3_3_8_0_2684.hex:
avrdude-slic3r: input file /Users/james.johnson/Downloads/prusa3d_fw_3_8_0_MK3 (1)/prusa3d_fw_MK3_3_8_0_2684.hex contains 244050 bytes
avrdude-slic3r: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 31.26s

avrdude-slic3r: verifying ...
avrdude-slic3r: 244050 bytes of flash verified

avrdude-slic3r done.  Thank you.

avrdude-slic3r -v -p atmega2560 -c arduino -P /dev/cu.usbmodem1421 -b 115200 -D -u -U flash:w:1:/Users/james.johnson/Downloads/prusa3d_fw_3_8_0_MK3 (1)/prusa3d_fw_MK3_3_8_0_2684.hex:i

avrdude-slic3r: Version 6.3-20160220-prusa3d, compiled on Sep 16 2019 at 02:08:32
                Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
                Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch


                Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbmodem1421
                Using Programmer              : arduino
                Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude-slic3r: prusa_init_external_flash(): MK3 printer emitted incorrect start code: `echo: `
avrdude-slic3r: arduino_open(): Failed to initialize MK3 external flash programming mode
avrdude-slic3r: Could not open port: /dev/cu.usbmodem1421

avrdude-slic3r done.  Thank you.
```

Pronterface error log repeats the same error continuously:

```
echo:busy: paused for user echo:busy: paused for user // action:pause Extruder fan speed is lower than expected echo:busy: paused for user echo:busy: paused for user echo:busy: paused for user echo:busy: paused for user echo:busy: paused for user echo:busy: paused for user echo:busy: paused for user echo:busy: paused for user // action:pause Extruder fan speed is lower than expected echo:busy: paused for user echo:busy: paused for user
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: I used Marlin 1.1.9 firmware and compiled and loaded it using the Arduino IDE. The printer works now. I was trying to use incompatible firmware.

Comment: Very good first question, welcome to 3DP.SE!

Comment: Although Prusa is a brand and the i3 and MK3 the model, it has become a model name for many other brands. Only if you have an original Prusa (you will know as they are more expensive than the clones) you can use the Prusa specific firmware, else you need to revert to e.g. open source alternatives as Repetier and Marlin or many more. Note that the Prusa firmware is based on Marlin, but only applicable to Prusa machines.

Answer (score 3):

I used Marlin 1.1.9 firmware and compiled and loaded it using the Arduino IDE. The printer works now. I was trying to use incompatible firmware.

[Marlin 1.1.9](http://marlinfw.org/meta/download/)

[Arduino IDE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/software)

Comment: Hi James, thanks for posting an answer on your own question! Thanks!

Comment: Please don't forget to accept your solution after 48 hours, happy printing!