# Connecting (Anet A8) 2004 display to MKS GEN L V2.0

Tags: lcd-screen, mks, display

Although it seems this question has been answered before [Connecting (Anet A8) 2004 display to MKS GEN L](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6030/connecting-anet-a8-2004-display-to-mks-gen-l) this one differs because the v2.0 board has no obvious AUX-2 connector.

So the question is, how can I connect the Anet A8 LCD Panel (with buttons) to the MKS Gen L V2.0 board? Or where can I find the schematics?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Thanks for posting a separate question! Note that it probably can be done, but not if you are using the UART, since there is no AUX-2 (and the LCD you want to connect requires analog pins) you need to "harvest" them from elsewhere unused pins. This includes changing your pins_xxx.h file. It is much easier to buy a new LCD that works with the EXP-1/2 ports.

Comment: Thanks Oscar for your buying advice. As you might know the challenge of fixing what you have often predominates good sense :-). I will think about harvesting or buying ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably can be done, but, it requires some splicing of your LCD cables (or using some Dupont male-female cables) and altering of the firmware pins header files.

The MKS GEN L v2.0 lacks the AUX-2 port that is present on the v1.0 controller boards. The reason for this is that they implemented support for more modern stepper drivers like the trinamic drivers that are capable of using UART to set stepper options.

The old v1.0 pin layout is displayed below:
[image: MKS GEN L v1.0 pin layout]

The new v2.0 pin layout is dislayed below:
[image: MKS GEN L v2.0 pin layout]

The Anet A8 2004 graphical display (so-called ZONESTAR_LCD) uses (at least one as the buttons are suited with different resistors) analog pin that is used to detect which buttons are pushed.

```
#elif ENABLED(ZONESTAR_LCD)
  #define ADC_KEYPAD_PIN 12
```

Pins `A5` and `A9-12`, `D40`, `D42` and `D44` are used according to the pin layout.

In the `pins_RAMPS.h` header file the display usage is coded as:

```
#elif ENABLED(ZONESTAR_LCD)

  #define LCD_PINS_RS                     64
  #define LCD_PINS_ENABLE                 44
  #define LCD_PINS_D4                     63
  #define LCD_PINS_D5                     40
  #define LCD_PINS_D6                     42
  #define LCD_PINS_D7                     65
```

In order for this to work on the MKS GEN L v2.0, you need to source for free pins that can mimic these pins and alter the header file and create a spliced LCD cable.

It might be much easier to buy a new reprap discount display controller for about 10 bucks/euros and connect it to the dedicated EXP1/2 headers. Stay away from the Anet A6 graphical display.

Comment: Thanks Oscar! The dices have chosen to buy one (done). Anyway, your valued answer gave me confidence about modding the board.

Comment: The keypad of the Anet A8 just uses one analog pin. In the pins_RAMPS.h file the is further down the definition #elif ENABLED(ZONESTAR_LCD) #define ADC_KEYPAD_PIN 12. The buttons are suited with different resistors. So using your answer and this hint will help to get it running. Finding some time next week I will try to set it up despite my purchase.