# How to use an Anet A8 control board with a damaged AVR IC?

Tags: extruder, anet-a8

- *This post was taken from [this comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/anet-a8-reading-739c-from-the-extruder-thermistor#comment9221_5097), as the OP did not repost [their deleted answer](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/anet-a8-reading-739c-from-the-extruder-thermistor#answer-6143) as a new question.*
- *See associated post on SE.Meta: [Is it possible to attribute a wiki post to a user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311849/is-it-possible-to-attribute-a-wiki-post-to-a-user)*

---

With respect to this question: [Anet A8 reading 739°C from the extruder thermistor!](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/anet-a8-reading-739c-from-the-extruder-thermistor)

Having read the issue, it seems that this is a common problem for the ANET3D board.  I'd like to ask two questions:

1. Is it possible to sever connections to the ATMEGA and use the hardware itself while controlled with the Raspberry Pi or some other dev board?
2. While waiting for a new board (seems to be the only cost/time effective choice), is there any way to use the other temperature circuit (likely having to do some work in Arduino IDE)?

My hot end decided to set itself to 265°C while my bed is reading the new thermistor on the new Hot End just fine.  I need to get a few prints made while waiting on funds to replace the board for full functionality.

I figure #1 is too much to hope for, but I have to ask. So, if you swap the heater circuits, what do you have to modify in `configuration.h` to convince the firmware to accept the modified input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This post was taken from [Tooniis's comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/anet-a8-reading-739c-from-the-extruder-thermistor#comment9222_5097).*

---

I've been doing #2 for a week now. I swapped ports of the nozzle and hotbed. Now I have a functional nozzle but the bed cannot be heated. The new hardware should arrive soon though. As for #1, it would be very hard to do since the ATmega chip is an SMD package.

In `sanguino.h` there are two lines which define the pins for the hotbed thermistor and the nozzle thermistor. One of them is `6` and the other is `7`, and I just swapped those two. The lines are next to each other.